# Reset data and query after use wp_dropdown_categories

Tags: wordpress

If I use this twice in one page, My categories list is merged to together!

I want reset query or empty data after use it.

```
function dropdownListCities( $selected=0 ){
    $id = "opalestate_location".rand();
    $args = array(
        'show_option_none' => '‌Select City',
        'id' => 'search'.$id,
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'name'  => 'location_search',
        'show_count' => 0,
        'hierarchical'  => '',
        'selected'  => $selected,
        'value_field'   => 'slug',
        'taxonomy'  => 'opalestate_location',
        'hide_empty' =>0
    );


    $dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );


    return $dropdown;

}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you trying like this `echo dropdownListCities();`?

Comment: I think it may be useful to you. Here the documentation for "wp_dropdown_categories". https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/